# How do i Assert in this test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-automation

I have a test class and when i gave the package for the security review the message was

> This rule identifies Apex Test Methods that do not Assert that the
>   code behaves properly. Verifying that your code works as you expect it
>   to work is the most important part of unit testing. It is important to
>   ensure that all test methods use the System.assert methods to prove
>   that the code behaves as expected. If you do not use any
>   System.assert() method calls, then the tests are not verifying results
>   properly.

Test class code is

```
@isTest 
private class AgentController3TestClass {

    static testMethod void SaveA()
    {

        seit__Agent_Table__c a = new seit__Agent_Table__c(seit__Email__c='beenishkhan.2012@gmail.com',seit__Agent_Name__c='adfasddf',seit__Salary__c=20000);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(a);
        AgentController3 controller = new AgentController3(sc);
        controller.SaveAgent();         
    }
    static testMethod void saveA1(){

        seit__Agent_Table__c pro = new seit__Agent_Table__c(seit__Email__c='beenishkhan.2012@gmail.com');
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(pro);
        AgentController3 controller = new AgentController3(sc);
        controller.SaveAgent();
    }

    static testMethod void editTest(){

        seit__Agent_Table__c pro4 = new seit__Agent_Table__c();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc4 = new ApexPages.standardController(pro4);
        AgentController3 controller4 = new AgentController3(sc4);
        controller4.editAgent();
    }
    static testMethod void editTest2(){

        seit__Agent_Table__c pr = new seit__Agent_Table__c(seit__Agent_Name__c='adfasdf');
        ApexPages.StandardController s = new ApexPages.standardController(pr);
        AgentController3 controll = new AgentController3(s);
        controll.editAgent();
    }
    static testMethod void searchTest(){

        seit__Agent_Table__c pro5 = new seit__Agent_Table__c();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc5 = new ApexPages.standardController(pro5);
        AgentController3 controller5 = new AgentController3(sc5);
        controller5.search();
    }
    static testMethod void cancelTest(){

        seit__Agent_Table__c pro6 = new seit__Agent_Table__c();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc6 = new ApexPages.standardController(pro6);
        AgentController3 controller6 = new AgentController3(sc6);
        controller6.cancel();
    }
}
```

My controller is

```
public with sharing class AgentController3 {
    public List<seit__Agent_Table__c> getAgent {get; set;}
    public seit__Agent_Table__c agent {get; set;}
    public string searchText {get;set;}
    public List<seit__Agent_Table__c> searchResults {get;set;}
    public boolean searchCheck {get;set;}

    public AgentController3(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        searchCheck=true;
        agent=new seit__Agent_Table__c();
        getAgent = [SELECT Id, Name,seit__Agent_Name__c, seit__Email__c, seit__Phone_Number__c, seit__Address__c,
        seit__Bank_Branch__c,seit__Salary__c,seit__Designation__c,seit__Company_Name__c,seit__User__c,seit__User_Name__c,CreatedDate FROM seit__Agent_Table__c order by seit__Agent_Name__c];
    }
    public pageReference SaveAgent()
    {
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/AgentDetailImproveVFPage?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1');
        try
        {
            upsert agent;   
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRef;  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            String errorMessage=ex.getMessage();
            system.debug(ex);
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public PageReference search() 
    {
        String qry='SELECT Id, Name,seit__Agent_Name__c , seit__Email__c, seit__Phone_Number__c, seit__Address__c,seit__Bank_Branch__c,seit__Salary__c,seit__Designation__c,seit__Company_Name__c,seit__User__c,seit__User_Name__c,CreatedDate FROM seit__Agent_Table__c where seit__Agent_Name__c LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\' order by seit__Agent_Name__c';
        searchResults = Database.query(qry);
        if(searchResults.isEmpty()==true || searchResults.size()==0)
        {
            searchResults=null;
            searchCheck=false;
        }
        else
        {
            searchCheck=true;  
        }
        return null; 
    }
    public PageReference editAgent() 
    {
        try 
        {
            update searchResults;
        } Catch (Exception e) 
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        return new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/AgentDetailImproveVFPage?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1');
    }
    public PageReference cancel() 
    {
        return new PageReference('/apex/AgentDetailImproveVFPage?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1');
    }
}
```

Comment: in save and search based on what are you doing validate them using assert.

Comment: @TusharSharma Please see the edit

Comment: There is not much difference between the tests `SaveA` and `SaveA1`, and the tests `editTest` and `editTest2`

Answer (score 1):

This question shows that what you're missing is not just a Salesforce technique, but the whole concept of what a unit test is supposed to do.

I would recommend doing some reading up on Test Driven Development to have an idea of what you're actually supposed to do when testing. Kent Beck's is a good starting point.

This is also a good resource on testing on Salesforce: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests

In any case the ideas that @Tushar Sharma gave are a good starting point. I would go a bit beyond and assert that your controller is actually returning the right results.

Comment: +1 for writing what I was going to about missing the concept. Clearly he can no longer apply TDD as the code is already written. I'm not sure I agree that the recommended assertions are "good." Besides being insufficient, they ignore the existence of `assertEquals` and `assertNotEquals` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try different assert based on your class. like

for search method

```
system.assert(controller.searchResults != null)
```

for edit method

```
system.assert(controller.editAgent.customfield == 'value'); //update any custom field value and use assert to validate
```

Also use this same pattern to validate in `savemethod`.

in cancel method try this

```
system.assert(controller.cancel() != null)
```

Comment: Tushar, are you aware there are `assertEquals` and `assertNotEquals` methods? They will give you *much* clearer results.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes i am aware of them but i am not aware about his current functionality. In this case `system.assert` is a good deal. and we can verify here too :) Thanks.